# triggers in SQLDeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

just curious if there is something I'm not doing correctly to get this trigger to fire when i update the ORDER table.... I have the trigger enabled, but when i insert into ORDER nothing gets printed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER inventory_avail
BEFORE INSERT ON order FOR EACH ROW     
  DECLARE
    v_quantity_diff   NUMBER;
    v_onhand_quantity NUMBER;   
  BEGIN
    SELECT inventory_onhand INTO v_onhand_quantity
    FROM inventory
    WHERE :new.fk_prod_id = inventory.fk_prod_id;

    v_quantity_diff := v_onhand_quantity - :new.quantity;

    dbms_output.PUT_LINE('QUANTITY DIFF: ' || TO_CHAR(v_quantity_diff));
  END;
```

Comment: It compiles and shows up in SQL developer, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes it is.  I know Oracle allows `order` as a table name even though it is a reserved word.  Just wondering.

Comment: @StillLearningToCode: try `BEFORE INSERT ON "ORDER" FOR EACH ROW`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I think I left a "don't" or something out of my comment.  In any case, the best solution is not to use a keyword.  For instance, `orders`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is a case, but but try setting the serveroutput before calling a trigger:

```
   set serveroutput on;
```